# AppDomain.DoCallBack() with multi generic types issue

Tags: c#, generics, appdomain

i've a strange issue with AppDomain.DoCallBack() and generic types:

```
static void InvokeIsolated() {
  AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("testDomain");
  appDomain.DoCallBack(MyDoCallBack<string, string>); <-- ArgumentNullException!
}

static void MyDoCallBack<T, T1>() {}
```

i get an argumentnullexpcetion with the message: "value cannot be null"
when the generic types are the same.

if i change the docallback to this:

```
appDomain.DoCallBack(MyDoCallBack<string, int>); <-- OK!
```

that means if the generic types are different, there is no problem.

what is wrong or is this a .net bug??

UPDATE:
lambda isn't a workaround if called with generic types:

```
static void Foo()
{
   InvokeIsolated<string, string>();
}

static void InvokeIsolated<T, T1>()
{
   AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("testDomain");
   appDomain.DoCallBack(() => MyDoCallBack<T, T1>()); //<--ArgumentNullException
}

static void MyDoCallBack<T, T1>() {}
```

Comment: Where do you get the `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: In order to help you we need the code for DoCallBack<T, T1>()

Comment: i get the ArgumentNullException on appDomain.DoCallBack(DoCallBack<string, string>);

Comment: DoCallBack is empty..

Comment: I can repro this. That's a bug in the C# compiler or the JIT. There is a `qword ptr [rax]` and the memory at `rax` seems unmapped since the VS memory window cannot display it.; Update: IL is fine so it's a JIT bug. `DoCallBack` just calls its argument according to Reflector. So it seems to get special JIT treatment or runs through the Remoting infrastructure. That can cause bugs.

Comment: @usr, generated IL is the same

Comment: @brainwave, Try with a lambda: `appDomain.DoCallBack(() => MyDoCallBack<string, string>());`

Comment: Exception seems to be thrown here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs,983

Comment: @haim770, same issue calling with lambda

Comment: @haim770 why do you think it's thrown there? That method is not called and it is not on the stack then the exception happens.

Comment: it's on stack:

   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   bei System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   bei System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   ...

Comment: @brainwave right. My debugger had "Just My Code" enabled. Classic mistake.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5.1 and it does show `MakeGenericMethod` on stack and it *does* work using a lambda.

Comment: @haim770 lambda does work because the lambda is not generic. Does not trigger the bug. The generic call is wrapped.

Comment: @usr, clearly. But OP asked for a workaround. Of course it has nothing to do with the possible framework bug here

Comment: cannot confirm this. lambda does not work for me:
appDomain.DoCallBack(() => MyDoCallBack<string, string>()); <-- same exception

Comment: OK, it's not a JIT bug but a Remoting infrastructure bug.

Comment: so no workaround exists?

Comment: @brainwave the lambda does work. You made a mistake trying to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the .NET Remoting infrastructure. This is a crash in .NET internal code.

I don't have a good workaround. You could compile a non-generic wrapping function using expression trees. You would need one such lambda per set of generic type arguments.

Comment: Any clue why is it happening only when the 2 generic parameters are the same?

Comment: I do not understand the bug. This is just a workaround answer.

Comment: @usr, please check my new comment

Comment: @brainwave I have added something. Try to make it work this way.

Comment: @usr, cannot compile this..something about the CrossAppDomaiDelegate has wrong arguments..because DoCallBack expect a CrossAppDomaiDelegate